# ModuleNotFoundError after pip install -e

Tags: relative-path, setup.py

I have the setup.py code as below:

```
from setuptools import setups, PEP420PackageFinder

setup(
   name='abc'
   ,packages=PEP420PackageFinder.find(include=['abc.*'],
                                      exclude=['abc.score_pipeline.x'])

)
```

And the file path is as below:

```
/current/
/current/setup.py
/current/abc/score_pipeline/x
/current/abc/score_pipeline/y
/current/abc/score_pipeline/y/lalala
```

Under `/current/` I ran `pip install -e`, which has no problem. 
Then in script I'd like to `from abc.score_pipeline.y import lalala`, but it complains `No Module named abc.score_pipeline`; I think I could import `abc`, but not `abc.score_pipeline`.

Why can't I import `abc.score_pipeline`? Really confused by this and driven crazy by such seemingly simple relative path issue.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` files anywhere? Is `/current/abc/score_pipeline/y/lalala` a directory or a file?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. have you found a way to resolve this?